# SQLSRV driver installation problem in Ubuntu 16.04 with php7

Tags: apache2, php, vps

Installed sqlsrv using following steps but not able to connect sql server express 2017

Step 1. Install PHP

```sh
apt-get update
apt-get -y install php7.0 mcrypt php7.0-mcrypt php-mbstring php-pear php7.0-dev php7.0-xml
```

Step 2. Install prerequisites

```sh
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql mssql-tools
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Step 3. Install the PHP drivers for Microsoft SQL Server

```sh
sudo pear config-set php_ini `php --ini | grep "Loaded Configuration" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"` system
sudo pecl install sqlsrv
sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
```

`db.php` (no message display after running this script)

```php
<?php
$serverName = "servername"; //serverName\instanceName

// Since UID and PWD are not specified in the $connectionInfo array,
// The connection will be attempted using Windows Authentication.
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"database", "UID"=>"user", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

could you please help?ubuntu 16.04.1 after running above script db.php it display blank page.

Comment: Please edit your question with code-syntax  ( 4 spaces tabulation) for the command blocks.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do to “run” the PHP script in question, what did you want to expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: I have the same issue ... did you fount the problem?